# Array indexing/Pointer arithmetic fails in a constexpr context

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, constexpr

I have a vector implementation and trying to place the stored values `T` in a wrapper.

The wrapper has the same memory layout as `T`, so doing array indexing/pointer arithmetic on a `T*` appears to work correctly at runtime. However, when trying to do the same in a `constexpr` context, [gcc, clang, msvc] all reject the code.
Note also that `data()[0]` works in all cases, but `data()[1]`, `data()[2]` etc fail.

Should this be the case? Why is the compiler deciding that is fine to do pointer arithmetic for `SimpleVector`, but not for `SimplerVector2`?
Furthermore, is the runtime pointer arithmetic (which appears to work) safe to use?

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cassert>

struct Wrapper
{
    double b;
};

struct SimpleVector
{
    std::array<double, 100> values;
    constexpr const double* data() const { return &values[0]; }
};

struct SimpleVector2
{
    std::array<Wrapper, 100> values;
    constexpr const double* data() const { return &values[0].b; }
};

int main()
{
    {
        constexpr SimpleVector my_vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        assert(my_vec.data()[0] == 1);  // OK
        assert(my_vec.data()[1] == 2);  // OK
        assert(my_vec.data()[2] == 3);  // OK
        static_assert(my_vec.data()[0] == 1);  // OK
        static_assert(my_vec.data()[1] == 2);  // OK
        static_assert(my_vec.data()[2] == 3);  // OK
    }

    {
        constexpr SimpleVector2 my_vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        assert(my_vec.data()[0] == 1);  // OK
        assert(my_vec.data()[1] == 2);  // OK
        assert(my_vec.data()[2] == 3);  // OK
        // OK!!
        static_assert(my_vec.data()[0] == 1);
        // FAILS! read of dereferenced one-past-the-end pointer
        // is not allowed in a constant expression
        static_assert(my_vec.data()[1] == 2);
        // FAILS! cannot refer to element 2 of non-array object
        // in a constant expression
        static_assert(my_vec.data()[2] == 3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Live code: https://godbolt.org/z/u_Mgtg

(Note: The reason I am trying to wrap the values is so I can do [optional_storage](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/constexpr-unions/), thus not requiring `T` to be default constructible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `SimpleVector`, the pointer returned is to an element of an array. The compiler knows how many elements are contained in the array and allows you to access any of those elements as part of a constexpr function.

`SimpleVector2::data` returns a pointer to a single double value. You can dereference it with `*`, or access the first element with `[0]`, but if you try to access element `[1]` you run into Undefined Behavior because the returned pointer is to a single value, not an array.  In this case, `SimpleVector2` probably is the same size as a `double` so you can get away with it at run-time.  However, any use of Undefined Behavior is not allowed in a `constexpr` which gives you the compiler error.

One possible change is if `SimpleVector2::data` would return a `Wrapper` by value, pointer, or reference.  Adding a `operator T` conversion method would make its use mostly transparent.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid exposing the `Wrapper` altogether, but, indeed, auto-conversion should be sufficiently transparent.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are returning single element `b` instead of pointer to array.

This will work if you'll do it like this:

```
struct SimpleVector2
{
    std::array<Wrapper, 100> values;
    constexpr const Wrapper* data() const { return &values[0]; }
};

//...
static_assert(my_vec.data()[0].b == 1);
static_assert(my_vec.data()[1].b == 2);
static_assert(my_vec.data()[2].b == 3);
```

But you probably want this:

```
struct SimpleVector2
{
    std::array<Wrapper, 100> values;
    constexpr const double& operator[] (size_t n) const { return values[n].b; }
};

//...
static_assert(my_vec[0] == 1);
static_assert(my_vec[1] == 2);
static_assert(my_vec[2] == 3);
```

Comment: I do have `operator[]`,  but wanted `.data()` as well to be closer to the API of `std::vector`. For that matter, I was hoping to hide `Wrapper` and return `T*` like `std::vector` does  (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), but an auto-conversion to `T*` should work.